# How to change a text, with sed, when want to match multiple lines

Tags: sed

I need to make some changes to a file but want to match multiple lines.

I tried something like `sed 's/name-here\n.*version: .*/name-here\nversion: new-version/g' file.yaml` but is not working

This is a peace of code from the file

```
name_here:
- name: name-here
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: other-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: final-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
```

After I'll use sed I want to end up with something like:

```
name_here:
- name: name-here
  version: new-version
- name: other-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: final-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
```

Comment: awk is better for this job. Is sed mandatory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the structure of the data, you can bodge it using a regular-expression range rather than trying to do multi-line stuff in `sed`. Really you should do this with a proper YAML tool.

Try

```
$ sed '/- name: name-here/,/  version:/s/version: .*/version: new-version/' <<END
name_here:
- name: name-here
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: other-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: final-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
END
name_here:
- name: name-here
  version: new-version
- name: other-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: final-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy job for `awk`

```
awk 'f && /version/ {$2="new version";f=0} /name-here/ {f=1} 1'file

name_here:
- name: name-here
version: new version
- name: other-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: final-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
```

If formatting is important, this should do:

```
awk 'f && /version/ {sub(/: .*/, ": new version");f=0} /name-here/ {f=1} 1' file
name_here:
- name: name-here
  version: new version
- name: other-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
- name: final-name
  version: 1.3.2.115
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/name-here/{:a;n;/version:/s/:.*/: new-version/;Ta}' file
```

Look for a line containing `name-here`, then amend the first line containing `version:`.

If you only want to replace the `version:` once in a file, use:

```
sed '/name-here/{:a;n;/version:/s/:.*/: new-version/;Ta;:b;n;bb}' file
```